# Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream+ LInkedin API Oauth2.0

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I was using the linkedin Api using Oauth2 and web request but today I found that it stoped working and I am getting the error
**Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream**
here are urls used by me 
AUTHORIZE = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization";
ACCESS_TOKEN = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken";
and the final url that is making call through the webrequest is
**grant_type=authorization_code&code=xxxxxxx&client_id=xxxxx&client_secret=xxxxx&redirect_uri=**

what is changed in this link oauth of linked in that causing this issue? 
I am using C#.

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer, but confirmation.  We have several integration points with LinkedIn within our enterprise, and the last logged time that we successfully had an OAuth session was on the 28th of June, at around 3a EST.  Spuriga's answer is likely correct, in that they removed support for specific TLS protocol versions in a weekend maintenance package.  Nothing on the developer blog about this, that I could find.  Very disappointing.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use before the request:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: yes I used it but after it exception comes "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request"

Comment: Try to use:
Auth: https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization AccessToken: https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken

Comment: ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; working Thanks.

Comment: I believe you'd be better off with an |= rather than = would you not? Otherwise you're disabling something higher like TLS1.3, if it's available.