# Authentication failed because the remote part has closed the transport stream

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, oauth-2.0

I am getting below error message when trying to get oauth2 token through external API from .net core console app but it is working fine in postman. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong here?
Error Message: "Authentication failed because the remote part has closed the transport stream".

Sample Code:

```js
var client = new HttpClient();
var collection = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>();
collection.Add(new("grant_type","client_credentials"));
collection.Add(new("client_id","***client_id****"));
collection.Add(new("client_secret","***client_secret*"));
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(collection);
request.Content = content;
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
Console.WriteLine(awaitresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

Comment: Several API's do require their authentication data in the headers of the request, others inside the form. I would suggest you to check that API documentation, it should mention the authentication method. For example [Google API](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#4.-send-the-access-token-to-an-api)

Comment: That error means something went wrong on the TLS level, your request isn't even sent. That you happen to be authenticating is a red herring.

Comment: Depending on your .NET version and OS it could be related to TLS. You might try the suggestion made here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51131565/authentication-failed-because-the-remote-party-has-closed-the-transport-stream?rq=2

Comment: @EmperorEto the solution almost always is not to downgrade your security, but to tell your service provider to upgrade theirs.

Comment: Specifying TLS1.2 is unlikely to be a downgrade, and also is sometimes necessary if the user is on an older machine like Windows 7. At least if it works it pinpoints the problem. Plus we have no idea if they have control over the service provider or not.

Comment: @Emperor deviating from SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault is problematic. It downgrades _all_ outgoing request from that application. You don't say it's a troubleshooting step in your first comment, you say they should try that. Almost nowhere where that is suggested (and there are dozens of answers around suggesting downgrading to 1.1 or 1.0 as well) people warn about the risks. So here I am.

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't think you're seeing my point. It's not necessarily a downgrade. There are some (albeit rare) cases where .NET doesn't include TLS 1.2 even if the OS supports it. I have experienced this. So my thought was try ensuring it's there explicitly and seeing if that makes a difference. The only thing I would add to the answer I linked to would be to |= 1.2 rather than make it exactly equal. I should've pointed that out earlier. That being said, if it turns out the OP DOES have to downgrade to 1.1 or something then at least they know the issue and can make an educated decision.